# Переменные  JavaScript, jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите понять, почему не работает следующий код:

```
var mass1;
$.get("info.txt", function(data){
   mass1 = data;
   alert("Data Loaded 1 : " + mass1);
});
alert("Data Loaded 2 : " + mass1);
```

`alert Data Loaded 1` выдает верные данные, а `alert Data Loaded 2` пуст!

Буду благодарен за ответ.

Леонид (l.lisachenko@gmail.com).

Comment: @Леонид05-05, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Леонид05-05, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Метод get асинхронный. Поэтому на момент вызова `alert("Data Loaded 2 : " + mass1);` данные еще не загружены с сервера. Происходит все как-то так:

```
var mass1; // объявляем глобальную переменную, что есть нехорошо.
// Отправляем запрос на сервер. Когда сервер вернет ответ вызываем callback-функцию. НО НЕ РАНЬШЕ, чем будет выполнен остальной код.
$.get("info.txt", function(data){ 
  mass1 = data;
  alert("Data Loaded 1 : " + mass1); });
// НЕ ДОЖИДАЯСЬ ответа сервера выполняем код дальше
alert("Data Loaded 2 : " + mass1); // очевидно, что тут в mass1 ничего быть не может.
```

Для полноты понимания погуглите про событийный цикл и асинхроннось в javascript.